# Pthreads returning before loop is complete, work seems to continue in the background

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, opencl

I've written a simple benchmark to test and measure the single-precision fused multiply add performance of both processors, and OpenCL devices.

I recently added SMP support using Pthread. The CPU side is simple, it generates a couple of random matrices for inputs to ensure that the work can't be optimized out by the compiler.

The function cpu_result_matrix() creates the threads, and blocks until every thread returns using pthread_join(). It's this function that's timed to determine the performance of the device.

```
static float *cpu_result_matrix(struct bench_buf *in)
{
        const unsigned tc = nthreads();
        struct cpu_res_arg targ[tc];

        float *res = aligned_alloc(16, BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(float));

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < tc; i++) {
                targ[i].tid = i;
                targ[i].tc = tc;
                targ[i].in = in;
                targ[i].ret = res;
        }

        pthread_t cpu_res_t[tc];

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < tc; i++)
                pthread_create(&cpu_res_t[i], NULL,
                               cpu_result_matrix_mt, (void *)&targ[i]);

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < tc; i++)
                pthread_join(cpu_res_t[i], NULL);

        return res;
}
```

The actual kernel is in cpu_result_matrix_mt():

```
static void *cpu_result_matrix_mt(void *v_arg)
{
        struct cpu_res_arg *arg = (struct cpu_res_arg *)v_arg;

        const unsigned buff_size = BUFFER_SIZE;
        const unsigned work_size = buff_size / arg->tc;
        const unsigned work_start = arg->tid * work_size;
        const unsigned work_end = work_start + work_size;

        const unsigned round_cnt = ROUNDS_PER_ITERATION;

        float lres;

        for (unsigned i = work_start; i < work_end; i++) {

                lres = 0;
                float a = arg->in->a[i], b = arg->in->b[i], c = arg->in->c[i];

                for (unsigned j = 0; j < round_cnt; j++) {
                        lres += a * ((b * c) + b);
                        lres += b * ((c * a) + c);
                        lres += c * ((a * b) + a);
                }

                arg->ret[i] = lres;
        }

        return NULL;
}
```

I noticed that the reported time taken for the kernel was roughly the same, regardless of how much I unrolled the inner loop.

To investigate, I made the kernel much larger by manually unrolling the inner loop until I could easily measure the wall time of the program running.

In the process, I observed that (it appears) the threads are returning before the kernel does the work it actually should do, which causes pthread_join() to stop blocking the main thread, and the execution time to appear to be much lower than it really is. I don't understand how this is possible, or how the program could continue to run and output correct results under these conditions.

Htop shows that the threads are still very much alive and working. I checked the return value of pthread_join(), and it was successful after every run. I got curious, and put a print statement in at the end of the kernel, before the return statement, and sure enough, each thread printed that it finished much sooner than it should have.

I watched ps while running the program, and it showed one thread, followed by three more, another five, then it dropped down to four.

I'm baffled, I've never seen threads act like this before.

The full source for my modified test branch is here: https://github.com/jakogut/clperf/tree/test

Comment: Based on the github I infer that you're using gcc and `-Ofast`. Have you checked to see if gcc is optimizing the inner loop over `j` away? A sum over `round_cnt` is equal to a single mult by `round_cnt` once you allow associative math.

Comment: i.e. `lres = round_cnt * (((b * c) + b) + b * ((c * a) + c) + c * ((a * b) + a));`

Comment: Excellent suggestion, I'm going to look into this. You should post this as an answer, and unless a better answer comes along, I'll accept yours.

Comment: You know, I just thought about it, and as much as I'd like to accept your answer, my program successfully verifies that the CPU results match the CL results at the end of the run. If the inner loop were being optimized out, I would think the results wouldn't match.

Comment: Optimizing out is a bit of a misnomer I mean being simplified. The results is the same but instead of doing the inner loop it simply does a multiplication. It should be easy to check the assembly.

Comment: I looked at the assembly. It still does the inner loop even with `-Ofast` (though the loop simpler with `-Ofast`).

Comment: Do not wait for something that may have already happened. You may be waiting a very long time.

Comment: Let me correct something I said. My statement that `lres = round_cnt * (((b * c) + b) + b * ((c * a) + c) + c * ((a * b) + a));` is incorrect. It turns out that e.g `a + a + a != 3*a` for floating point arithmetic and this has nothing to do with associative math. So even with `-Ofast` gcc cannot reduce the inner loop to a simple multiplication. But as I showed the expression in the inner loop is calculated before the inner loop and the inner loop becomes a simple sum of a constant. That's why it's fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the process, I observed that (it appears) the threads are returning before the kernel does the work it actually should do, which causes pthread_join() to stop blocking the main thread, and the execution time to appear to be much lower than it really is.

I'm not sure how you determine this. But looking at the assembly with `-Ofast` shows that

```
res[i] += a * ((b * c) + b);
res[i] += b * ((c * a) + c);
res[i] += c * ((a * b) + a);
```

is calculated *before* the inner loop.  The inner loop is effectively

```
float t = a * ((b * c) + b) + b * ((c * a) + c) + c * ((a * b) + a);
float sum = 0;
for (unsigned j = 0; j < ROUNDS_PER_ITERATION; j++) {
    sum += t;     
}
res[i] = sum;
```

If in your timing you're expecting your inner loop to do `sum += a * ((b * c) + b) + b * ((c * a) + c) + c * ((a * b) + a)` each iteration when in fact it only does `sum += t` then your timing estimate will be much larger than what you observe.

Comment: It seems what I need to do is fold the result back into the operands, then add the operands together for the output at the end of the inner loop. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

OpenMP seems to be a much better solution. It requires far less setup and complexity with problems like this that can exploit data parallelism.

```
static float *cpu_result_matrix(struct bench_buf *in)
{
        float *res = aligned_alloc(16, BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(float));

        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {

                float a = in->a[i], b = in->b[i], c = in->c[i];

                for (unsigned j = 0; j < ROUNDS_PER_ITERATION; j++) {
                        res[i] += a * ((b * c) + b);
                        res[i] += b * ((c * a) + c);
                        res[i] += c * ((a * b) + a);
                }
        }

        return res;
}
```

However, that doesn't answer why pthreads were behaving like they were in the question.